# Add two displacement modifiers to one object (additive)

Tags: mesh, displacement

#### What I want to do

I would like to add an additional displacement to my already displaced plane. this should enhance the detail as my first displacement is of limited resolution.

#### What my problem is

When adding a second displacement map, the already displaced plane gets badly distorted (like when overdoing the effect of the ocean modifier). When using the second displacement map without the first, it works fine and vice versa.

#### Information

**System info**
Macbook with M1 Max
Metal GPU
Blender 3.5.1
**Object info**
Plane
Scale applied
10 times Subdivided
**Displacement Info**
First Displacement was created with the GIS add-on an the SRTM Data
Second Displacement is a downloaded 4K B&W displacement Map of a Mountain
 [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your texture-images sound like height maps... in which case, for addition of heights, the displacements should be in your height-direction. (By the look of it: Z ).

In the first displacement of an XY grid, the 'Normal' direction **is** Z. In the second displacement, not so.

Comment: i don't know why i didn't check/try this first.. Thank you very much!